# JavaScript function declaration error

Tags: javascript, function

I just started learning JS and programming one small game for training. But I get a weird error while executing this object:

```
mainState = {
    name : "GAME_STATE",

    Setup: function( context, settings ) {
    }


    HandleKeyDown: function( event ) {
    }

    Update: function( settings ){

    }

    Draw: function( context, settings ){

    }
}
```

And all that FireBug says is:

```
SyntaxError: missing } after property list
HandleKeyDown: function( event ) {
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: you must adding comma after every element in object mainState, not only name, and after function Setup, HandleKeyDown...Good luck

Answer (score 1):

You need to put comma between properties (key and its value), otherwise it is not a valid JavaScript Object and hence this compilation error thrown by Firebug

> SyntaxError: missing } after property list

Here is the correct way to do it

```js
mainState = {
  name: "GAME_STATE",
  Setup: function(context, settings) {},
  HandleKeyDown: function(event) {},
  Update: function(settings) {},
  Draw: function(context, settings) {} // here no comma
}
```

Comment: It is a javascript object, not a JSON.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, you can easily create javascript objects, but first you must know the notation:

```
var jsObj1 = {}; //A very basic initiation.
var jsObj2 = {
    a: "a",
    b: "b",
    c: "c"
};
```

Here, as you can see, there are commas between every field of a JS object. For your situation here, you have created functions for each of your JS object's fields' values but forgot to put commas:

```
var mainState = {

    name : "GAME_STATE",

    Setup: function( context, settings ) {

    },

    HandleKeyDown: function( event ) {

    },

    Update: function( settings ) {

    },

    Draw: function( context, settings ) {

    }

};
```

So this will work without any error.

Comment: Fairly identical to @gurvinder372's answer, no?

Answer (score 0):

You  need add commas:

```
mainState = {
    name : "GAME_STATE",

    Setup: function( context, settings ) {
    },


    HandleKeyDown: function( event ) {
    },

    Update: function( settings ){

    },

    Draw: function( context, settings ){

    }
}
```